# Process Kill during execution of Nunit tests

Tags: .net, nunit, cruisecontrol.net

I have a test project that takes alot of time to test cases. I have configured cruisecontrol.net with Nunit, msbuild. Now if I run my project during the execution of Nunit it kills the process and fail the build. Also if you force a build then results are not updated it shows the last build results and also giving Textfixturesetup failed after viewing the results even if the tests passes.

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "run your project during the execution of NUnit"?  Do you mean that you have CCNet and Visual Studio on the same box?

If that's the case, then you probably do not want that configuration.  Start with putting CCNet on a separate machine.

Comment: On my machine nunit, vs2005, cc.net are installed. I am running the nightly builds having 3 projects in server. Problem is during execution build fails saying process killed due to timeout. Also shows old nunit resultys even I am running a clean workingcopy.

Comment: Any idea why it is occuring. Should I uninstall VS2005 from machine running cc.net server

Comment: Unless you have Visual Studio installation projects, you should not need Visual Studio on the same machine as ccnet.  Try uninstalling and see whether that helps resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks rather similar to [another one of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734484/process-timeout-without-showing-any-error-in-test-execution-using-cc-net/916342#916342).  See answers there for more info.